# Save mongoose document again after deleting it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I try to unit test my restify node.js-app using mocha and without mocking out the mongodb database. As some tests will alter the database, I'd like to reset its contents before each test.

In my tests I also need to access the mongoose documents I am creating. Thus I have to define them outside of the `beforeEach` hook (see the `user` document below).

However, it seems like it's not possible to save a document a second time after emptying the database.

Below is a minimal example I've come up with. The second test will fail in that case, because `user` won't get saved a second time. If I delete the first test, `beforeEach` only gets called once and everything works nicely.
Also if I define `user` inside the `beforeEach` hook, it works as well.

So my actual question: Is it possible to work around this issue and save a document a second time after deleting it? Or do you have any other idea on how I can reset the database inside the `beforeEach` hook? What's the proper way to have the same database setup before each test case?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var should = require('should')
var flow = require('async')

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  name: {type: String, default: ''}
})

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

var User = mongoose.model('User')

describe('test mocha', function() {
  var user = new User({
    username: 'max',
    password: 'asdf'
  })

  before(function(done) {
    var options = {server: {socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}}}
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/unittest', options, done)
  })

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    flow.series([
      function(callback) {
        User.collection.remove(callback)
      }, function(callback) {
        user.save(callback)
      }
    ], function(err, res) {
      done()
    })
  })

  it('should pass', function(done) {
    true.should.equal(true)
    // also access some elements of user here
    done()
  })

  it('should have a user', function(done) {
    User.find().exec(function(err, res) {
      res.should.not.be.empty
    })
    done()
  })

  after(function(done) {
    mongoose.disconnect()
    done()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem,I generated a copy of the document to save. When need to save the document after deleting it I saved the copy, and it worked. Like

```
      var user = new User({
            username: 'max',
            password: 'asdf'
            });
       var userCopy = new User({
            username: 'max',
            password: 'asdf'
            });
```

And in test cases.

```
     user.remove(callback)
  }, function(callback) {
    userCopy.save(callback){
      // should.not.exist(err)
     }
  }
```

It might not be good solution ,but it worked for me.